Do all species of wasps eat nectar?
There are many species of wasps, some of them are consuming other insects and meat. But do those wasps that eat insects also eat nectar from flowers? Are there known species of wasps that are solely carnivores?
An article about what wasps eat says that

most adult wasps feed primarily on sugary substances like nectar.

However I don't know if they refer to all known species of wasps and if that means there some wasps that do not eat nectar.

Vespid wasps that consume other insects, etc. do so during their larval stage, but feed almost exclusively on sugars as adults. Those sugars primarily come from flower nectar, but they can also come from things like aphid honeydew. They occasionally feed on pollen as well.
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-29654-4_14
